# iOS 9 crash - Unrecognized selector sent to instance; selector is valid property

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

**Note: This crash only occurs in iOS 9**

I have this subclass:

```
@interface PTSwitch : UIControl

@property (nonatomic) BOOL on;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger identifier;

- (void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

When I try to access the "identifier" property...

```
alertSwitch.on = YES;
alertSwitch.identifier = 1;
```

...I get an exception:

```
-[PTSwitch setIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have verified in the debugger that the object is indeed my subclass. Additionally, as you can see, called immediately before `identifier` is the `on` property, which is accessed without a problem.

```
po alertSwitch
<PTSwitch: 0x1383620f0; baseClass = UISwitch; frame = (257 62; 51 31); alpha = 0.5; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 666; layer = <CALayer: 0x136dd1800>>

po [alertSwitch class]
PTSwitch
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that the debugger seems to think the base class is UISwitch. I have no idea why this is, as clearly the base class is UIControl. I have no explanation for this but suspect it might be related.

Side note, this crash began happening on a version that was built with Xcode 7 for iOS 8 and was not rebuilt to cause the app to start crashing.

Comment: As a test, try renaming the property. Maybe there's some conflict somewhere in iOS 9 causing a property with that name to be read-only.

Comment: try (nonatomic,assign)

Comment: @Mr.T `assign` is the default. That would make no difference.

Comment: Tried both of these things before posting question.

Comment: @teh1 And what happened when you tried renaming the property? Same issue but with the new name?

Comment: Yes. Tried renaming property and tried adding assign. Neither make any difference in the outcome. I am thoroughly baffled.

Comment: It shouldn't be needed but try adding an explicit `readwrite` to the property declaration.

Comment: No difference, as expected. Keep in mind the last sentence in my question. I never had to re-build for the crash to start occurring.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a second `PTSwitch` class somehow coming into the picture in iOS 9. That would explain the unexpected base class and the missing property. Try renaming your `PTSwitch` class to `PTXSwitch` or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rmaddy, that was a very helpful hint

I did a quick search for "PTSwitch" on google and found a reference to a runtime header in iOS 8.3+. I'm not sure why I did not experience this crash until iOS 9, but it is definitely resolved now.

Solution: rename class to something other than PTSwitch.

Comment: I guess Apple was serious when they said ["we reserve all two-letter prefixes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW4).